# How do I get both chapter names linked to the header, if I have two chapters on a single page?

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I'd like to find out how I can have two chapters linked to my header.

I'm using

```
\ihead{\headmark}
```

to get the names of the current chapter into the header.

Document-class and loaded packages:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,oneside]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\usepackage{nameref} 
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain
\clearscrheadfoot

\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\ihead{\headmark}  

\setheadsepline{0,4pt} 
\setfootsepline{0,4pt}  
\rofoot{Seite \thepage\ von 11}
\lofoot{Protokoll: ...,...}

\setheadwidth{text}
\setfootwidth{text}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\parindent 0pt 
\parskip 0pt

\title{\textbf{Protokoll: Versuch 10/1 - Dünne Linsen}\vspace*{20mm}}
%
\author{\rmfamily von \textbf{...} und \textbf{...}\\
\\\textbf{\rmfamily Assistent:}\rmfamily\ ...} 
%
%
\date{\textbf{\rmfamily Datum:}\rmfamily\ 26. Mai 2014 - 02. Juni 2014}



\begin{document}
```

Also I used:

```
\listoffigures
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[foo] bar baz
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

to get the bibliography and the list of figures on the same page.

But now I have the problem that on the page including the chapters "bibliography" and "list of figures" I get only the name of the "list of figures"-chapter in the header. I think this is caused by the fact, that normally there is only one chapter per page.

[image: Page with 2 chapters. But only the name of the "list of figures"(Abbldungsverzeichnis) chapter is in the header]

But because I have the two chapters "bibliography" and "list of figures" on a single page, I'd like to know how I can have both names of the chapters linked to the header.

Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: You might try issuing `\markboth{\listfigurename\ -- \bibname}{}` after `\listoffigures`.

Comment: First, thanks!

But I don't exactly get what you meant. If I try 

    \markboth{\listfigurename\ -- \bibname}{}

It just seems to ignore that command. I don't even get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define a right mark as soon as possible:

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,oneside]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\usepackage{nameref} 
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last, with a few exceptions

\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain
\clearscrheadfoot

\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\ihead{\headmark}  

\setheadsepline{0,4pt} 
\setfootsepline{0,4pt}  
\rofoot{Seite \thepage\ von 11}
\lofoot{Protokoll: ...,...}

\setheadwidth{text}
\setfootwidth{text}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\parindent 0pt 
\parskip 0pt

\title{\textbf{Protokoll: Versuch 10/1 - Dünne Linsen}\vspace*{20mm}}
%
\author{\rmfamily von \textbf{...} und \textbf{...}\\
\\\textbf{\rmfamily Assistent:}\rmfamily\ ...} 
%
%
\date{\textbf{\rmfamily Datum:}\rmfamily\ 26. Mai 2014 - 02. Juni 2014}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cleardoublepage
\markright{\listfigurename\ -- \bibname}
\listoffigures
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[foo] bar baz
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]